# ReactJS component only recognizes first parameter I pass

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typeerror

I'm encountering an issue where a modal component only receives the first parameter I send it but I need it to recognize both parameters or else the modal has no use. Basically, right now I can choose whether I put my `TaskProps` or a `closeModal` function as the first parameter. If the `TaskProps` are the first parameter, the `closeModal` function gets a TypeError and does not get recognized as a function. If I put `closeModal` as the first parameter, I'm able to close the modal but I can't work with the `TaskProps` to show details about certain tasks.

Here's my (relevant) code:

index.js ->

```
const TaskList = (state: TaskSectionState, task): React$Element<React$FragmentType> => {
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([])
    const [isSortDropdownOpen, setIsSortDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
    const [selectedTask, setSelectedTask] = useState(tasks[1]);
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false)
    
    const selectTask = (task) => {
        setSelectedTask(task);
        setOpenModal(!openModal)
    };
    
    {openModal && <DetailModal {...selectedTask } closeModal={setOpenModal}  />}
```

DetailModal.js ->

```
type TaskProps = {
    id: number,
    title: string,
    assigned_to: string,
    assignee_avatar: string,
    due_date: string,
    completed: boolean,
    priority: string,
    stage: string,
    checklists: Array<ChecklistsItems>,
    description: string,
    attachments: Array<AttachmentsItems>,
    comments: Array<CommentsItems>,
};

const DetailModal = (task: TaskProps, {closeModal}): React$Element<React$FragmentType> => {
    const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(task.completed == true);
    
    return (
        <React.Fragment >
            <Modal show={true}>
            <Card>
                <Card.Body>
                   <h3>Task Details</h3>
                    <hr className="mt-4 mb-2" />

                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                        <p className="mt-2 mb-1 text-muted">Title</p>
                            <h4>{task.title}</h4>

                            <Row>

                                <Col>
                                    <p className="mt-2 mb-1 text-muted">Deadline</p>
                                    <div className="d-flex">
                                        <i className="uil uil-schedule font-18 text-primary me-1"></i>
                                        <div>
                                            <h5 className="mt-1 font-14">{task.due_date}</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>

                            <div className="row mt-3">
                                <div className="col">
                                <p className="mt-2 mb-1 text-muted">Description</p>
                                    <div id="taskDesk" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(task.description)}></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="row mt-3">
                                <div className="col">
                                    <h5 className="mb-2 font-16">Notes</h5>
                                    <p>Add notes/remarks for your future-self down below.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            {/* add comments */}
                            <Row className="mt-2">
                                <Col>
                                    <div className="border rounded">
                                        <form action="#" className="comment-area-box">
                                            <textarea
                                                rows="3"
                                                className="form-control border-0 resize-none"
                                                placeholder="Your comment..."></textarea>
                                            <div style={{height: "60px"}} className="p-2 bg-light">
                                                <div className="float-end">
                                                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                                                        <i className="uil uil-message me-1"></i>Add Note
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <Link to="#" className="btn btn-sm px-1 btn-light">
                                                    </Link>
                                                    <Link to="#" className="btn btn-sm px-1 btn-light">
                                                    </Link>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </Col>
                                <div className="text-end"  style={buttonStyle} >
                                <Button variant="light"type="button" className="me-1" 
                                onClick={() => closeModal(false)}>
                                    Close
                                </Button>
                                <Button variant="secondary">
                                    Update Details
                                </Button>
                            </div>

                            </Row>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
            </Modal>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default DetailModal;
```

To make things maybe a bit more clear, if I pass my parameters in the manner which is shown above in DetailModal.js (`TaskProps` first and `closeModal` second) the details get rendered in the modal but the following TypeError shows up when clicking the 'Close' button:

[image]

And when I pass the parameters the other way around like this I'm able to close the modal perfectly fine but the `TaskProps` don't get passed and it just leaves blank fields. (See screenshot)

```
const Task = ({closeModal}, task: TaskProps): React$Element<React$FragmentType> => {
    const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(task.completed == true);
```

[image]

I would love to finally get past this headache because I can't seem to figure it out myself. I appreciate any input tremendously!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I destructure a React prop and still access other props?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64547597/how-can-i-destructure-a-react-prop-and-still-access-other-props)

Answer (score 2):

For react components first argument is an object representing all the props passed to it. So in your case for it to work you have to do it this way:

```
const DetailModal = ({closeModal, ...task}) => {
```

This way, you are destructuring `closeModal` from this object and keeping all the other props grouped together as a `task`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Gleb! That immediately fixed it.

Comment: Great to know it helped! I would appreciate if you mark it as an accepted answer then :)